# react render div if loop was empty

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering a list and I want to show an info that data was not loaded.

Here is my code:

```
<div className="dashboard-table dashboard-table-done">
           <div className="dashboard-table-title dashboard-table-title-done">Chamadas encerradas</div>
                    { this.state.data && this.state.data.map(attendInfo =>
                        attendInfo.close && (
                            <DashboardAttend {...attendInfo} />
                        )

                    )}
```

If attendInfo.close then renders `<DashboardAttend>`

If no one  was rendered I want to render a message saying that no one data was rendered like:

```
<div>No one data was found</div>
```

I can't use this.state.data because the field close can be null and length can be higther than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
render(){
    const dataForRender = this.state.data? this.state.data.filter((attendInfo) => {
       return attendInfo.close;
    }): [];

    return (
         <div className="dashboard-table dashboard-table-done">
             <div className="dashboard-table-title dashboard-table-title-done">
                 Chamadas encerradas
             </div>
             { 
                dataForRender.length>0 ? dataForRender.map(attendInfo =>
                  (
                          <DashboardAttend {...attendInfo} />
                  )
                ): <div>No one data was found</div>
             }
         </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use `lodash.some` for an early return e.g. `const isEmpty = !_.some(this.state.data, "close")` then `if (isEmpty) { return <div>No one data was found</div>;  }`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is if `state.data` is empty or contains no elements, then you want to write:

```
<div>No one data was found</div>
```

You can do this by simple adding another bit to the end:

```
{ (!state.data || !state.data.length) && <div>No one data was found</div> }
```

So in position it would look something like:

```
<div className="dashboard-table dashboard-table-done">
           <div className="dashboard-table-title dashboard-table-title-done">Chamadas encerradas</div>
                    { this.state.data && this.state.data.map(attendInfo =>
                        attendInfo.close && (
                            <DashboardAttend {...attendInfo} />
                        )

                    )}
                    { (!state.data || !state.data.length) && <div>No one data was found</div> }
```

Comment: I can't use state.data.length because state.data.length is higther than zero, but the length of list that contains attendInfo.close == null can be zero

Comment: Sounds like you need to reduce your data beforehand then.  Only you know what empty means in this case.

Comment: Can I add a counter before <DashboardAttend {...attendInfo} />? I need something similar this to check if <DashboardAttend {...attendInfo} /> was render (or not) at least one time